# Problems joining in Magento

Tags: php, magento

```
Table 1
--------------
|reseller_id |
|1           |
|2           |
|3           |
|4           |
--------------

Table 2
-------------------------------
|reseller_id | merchandise_id |
|1           | 1              |
|1           | 3              |
|2           | 1              |
|2           | 4              |
|3           | 2              |
-------------------------------

select * from reseller_maps inner join reseller_merch on reseller_maps.reseller_id = reseller_merch.reseller_id;
```

Is giving me what I'm looking for on the database side of things. However, I'm getting an

```
 Call to undefined method Namespace_Class_Model_Mysql4_Reseller_Collection::joinTable()
```

When trying to do $collection->joinTable() in Magento.

I've tried using getSelect and join():

```
        $collection = Mage::getModel('maps/reseller');
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->join( array( 'reseller_merch'=>$this->getTable('reseller_merch')), 'reseller_maps.reseller_id= reseller_merch.reseller_id', array('reseller_merch.*'));
```

and am getting:

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''
```

As far as I can tell this is directly from the example code on the wiki: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: use Mage::getModel('maps/reseller')->getCollection();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're subclassing a standard collection, it should be:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join($this->getTable('maps/[table_entity]'), 'main_table.reseller_id= reseller_merch.reseller_id');
```

This is assuming your entities are named this way.